# cr.setup in rms

Tags: r, modeling

Could someone please explain how the `cr.setup` functions in `rms` package works? I can't seem to figure out how it remaps the initial data and **how this remapping is useful for the continuation ratio model** and the help and examples are not that helpful. Can't find any other explanation on the net either.

Comment: have you looked at the function by typing `cr.setup`?

Comment: You're basically telling that you can't understand the function then. Why don't you copy the function and just test step by step with an input?

Comment: No. I am basically telling that I cannot understand how the remapping that the 'cr.setup' provides (which I find difficult to comprehend) reshapes the data to enter a continuation ratio model. I am not asking about the mechanics of the function which is relative simple. I am asking the role of the function in relation to its purpose.

Comment: aha, I understand.. I'm sorry I wont be of much help then..

Comment: Please feel free to edit my question if you feel that I am being vague

Comment: Voting to reopen. Already have a response composed and it is definitely an R-coding response. In case my reopening efforts fail (as I expect they will since I have never seen a successful reopening) , I will note that pages 338-342 of Harrell's "Regression Modeling Strategies" have the expanded background I was going to cite.

Comment: geez, you have the answer I am looking for and now I have to wait for someone to reopen...One of the things i hate in SO...

Comment: yes, but you don't have to wait very long!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In his excellent text "Regression Modeling Strategies" Harrell has three pages at the end of his chapter on ordinal logistic regression devoted to the continuation ratio model. `cr.setup` is supporting the process of "tricking ordinary logistic regression" by duplicating certain rows and creating stratum markers for various comparisons: `Y >= 0; Y>=1, ... Y>=K-1` and also creating appropriate response variables to represent the "outcome" for particular strata. Look at his first example for cr.setup:

```
y <- c(NA, 10, 21, 32, 32)
> cr.setup(y)
$y
[1] NA  1  0  1  0  0  0  0

$cohort
[1] <NA>  all   all   y>=21 all   y>=21 all   y>=21
Levels: all y>=21

$subs
[1] 1 2 3 3 4 4 5 5

$reps
[1] 1 1 2 2 2
```

With three levels of non-NA Y's,  there would be only 2 levels of the neo-outcome. The y vector is the neo-outcome.  The `subs` vector elements are the indices inot the original data. The `reps` vector tells the software how many replications are needed. You can see how this is used in practice by following down the example :

```
combinations <- expand.grid(cohort=levels(cohort), sex=levels(sex))
combinations
```

Comment: A little bit of this information is available through the Amazon preview: http://www.amazon.com/Regression-Modeling-Strategies-Applications-Statistics/dp/1441929185 Look at section 13.4.  The details of the R code are not available, but there's a lot of good general background there which might help.  I also **strongly** recommend just buying the book if you can afford it; you can get a 20% discount via http://www.r-project.org/doc/bib/springer.txt

Comment: DWin & Ben Bolker: Thank you for your replies (I ordered the book, gracias Ben for the -20%!). I still don't get it. Why is this remapping necessary to fit CR models? What does remapping essentially achieve? How should I interpret the coef? How do I get the unconditional probs from regression coefficients for each outcome level? I guess what I am missing is a **good example** with comments on each step (the one in the help file is bad one with no explanations whatsoever). And there  is surprisingly little info on the net about CR. Could you please help me? Will be glad to start a bounty..

Comment: large parts of this sound more suitable for CrossValidated ( http://stats.stackoverflow.com ) ... googling `ordinal regression "continuation ratio"` got me a fair bit, seems like *some* of it should be useful ...

Comment: It's NOT necessary as explained in that book section. It's merely convenient for purposes that are explained. I also think it helps make the model more "accessible". I see a parallel with the situation that existed 25 years ago when the 'other way' to get conditional logistic regression estimates (besides using the FORTRAN special purpose code on the VAX) was to code the case-control groupings as strata in a Cox model. (And I agree this discussion is more suitable for CrossValidated. I tried to reopen the question because it seemed R-specific at the time.)